# Computing the loss of a function of predictions with pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, autograd

I have a convolutional neural network that predicts 3 quantities: Ux, Uy, and P. These are the x velocity, y-velocity, and pressure field. They are all 2D arrays of size [100,60], and my batch size is 10.

I want to compute the loss and update the network by calculating the CURL of the predicted velocity with the CURL of the target velocity. I have a function that does this: v = curl(Ux_pred, Uy_pred). Given the *predicted* Ux and Uy, I want to compute the loss by comparing it to ground truth targets that I have: true_curl = curl(Ux_true, Uy_true) - I've already computed the true curl and added it to my Y data, as the fourth channel.

However, I want my network to only predict Ux, Uy, and P. I want my NN parameters to update based on the LOSS of the curls to improve the accuracy of Ux and Uy. The loss of the curl has to be in terms of Ux and Uy. I have been trying to do this using Pytorch autograd, and have already read many similar questions, but I just can't get it to work. This is my code so far:

```
        print("pred_Curl shape:", np.shape(pred_curl))
        print("pred_Ux shape:", np.shape(pred[:,0,:,:]))
        print("pred_Uy shape:", np.shape(pred[:,1,:,:]))
        true_curl = torch.from_numpy(y[:,3,:,:]) # not sure where to use the true curl?

        pred_curl = Variable(pred_curl, requires_grad=True)
        
        pred_ux = pred[:,0,:,:]
        pred_uy = pred[:,1,:,:]

        pred_ux = Variable(pred_ux, requires_grad=True)
        pred_uy = Variable(pred_uy, requires_grad=True)

        grad_tensor = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=pred_curl, inputs=(pred_ux, pred_uy), 
                       grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(pred_curl), 
                       retain_graph=True,create_graph=True)

        loss = torch.sum(grad_tensor)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

This has the following output:

```
pred_Curl shape: torch.Size([10, 100, 60])
pred_Ux shape: torch.Size([10, 100, 60])
pred_Uy shape: torch.Size([10, 100, 60])

RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph. 
Set allow_unused=True if this is the desired behavior.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Here is my curl function:

```
    def discrete_curl(self,x,y,new_arr):
            for m in range(100):
                for n in range(60):
                    if n <= 58:
                        if m <= 98:
                            if x[m,n] != 0 and y[m,n] != 0:
                                new_arr[m,n] = ((y[m+1,n] - y[m-1,n]) / 2*1) - ((x[m,n+1] - x[m,n-1]) / 2*1)
            return new_arr
```

Where x and y are Ux ad Uy, and new_arr is the curl output.

Comment: Are you asking what would be an appropriate loss function? I did not quite understand your third paragraph.

Comment: I'm asking how to compute the loss of the curl based on the data used in the neural network: which is Ux and Uy, so that the optimizer adjusts the model parameters accordingly!

Comment: Am I correct that a correct prediction of Ux and Uy would involve getting them equal to Ux_true and Uy_true? If so, I think you need to decide on an appropriate metric by which you wish to compare the true and predicted curls. For example, the MSE loss minimizes the squared L2 norm between the prediction and the ground truth. Once you have the loss, PyTorch can compute the derivatives, backpropagate the gradients, and update the network weights to make Ux and Uy closer to Ux_true and Uy_true.

Comment: Yeah, I can't just compute the loss without autograd, it doesn't work. I need to differentiate the curl with respect to the variables of interest: Ux and Uy. And that is where I'm running into issues

Comment: It is not clear to me why you are manually trying to compute gradients. You could for instance do `loss = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(pred_curl, true_curl)` and keep the rest of your code as it is. The differentiation will be done automatically when you call `loss.backward()`. Any reason that won't work in your case? (Btw, I am assuming that the curl is a piecewise differentiable function. If not, that makes things difficult.)

Comment: When I try to just do that, I get this error: RuntimeError: element 0 of variables does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn. Also, I've added my curl function above.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
def discrete_curl(self, pred):
        new_arr = torch.zeros((pred.shape[0],100,60))
        for pred_idx in range(pred.shape[0]):
            for m in range(100):
                for n in range(60):
                    if n <= 58:
                        if m <= 98:
                            if pred[pred_idx,0,m,n] != 0 and pred[pred_idx,1,m,n] != 0:
                                new_arr[pred_idx,m,n] = ((pred[pred_idx,1,m+1,n] - pred[pred_idx,1,m-1,n]) / 2*1) - ((pred[pred_idx,0,m,n+1] - pred[pred_idx,0,m,n-1]) / 2*1)
        return new_arr 

pred_curl = discrete_curl(pred)
true_curl = torch.from_numpy(y[:,3,:,:])
loss = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(pred_curl, true_curl)
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

I think the curl computation can be optimized, but I tried to stick to your structure for the most part.

Comment: Thank you. That gives me the following error, I could not solve yet: RuntimeError: leaf variable has been moved into the graph interior

Comment: @user3611 Sorry, can you try removing `requires_grad=True` in the declaration of `new_arr`?

Comment: Thank you. When I do that, it runs, but the loss remains 'nan'.

Comment: @user3611 Can you put `torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)` at the start of your script and check the output? It should give a hint on what causes the nan. It's possible it could be due to this block of code, but might also be due to other reasons, such as the data, the hyperparameters, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I've gotten past that error now, and its running. However, it's not working as expected. It's not updating in a way that brings down the loss between the predicted and real curl. The loss is staying fixed.

Comment: @user3611 Can you provide further details? If it is not related to this answer, it might be better to create a new post.